# Problem in setting up Cruise Control in RAILS 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cruisecontrol, cruisecontrol.rb

I just setup cruise control on my server for my projects . 
But now i am little bit confused how these rake task and capistrano work .
I tried lots of settings but still no success . If somebody help how to run all rake task and after successful build how can i deploy my application .

Comment: You don't ned to use capistrano for cruise-control. Your cruise control should be checking source-control for new versions, and building when it finds one.

Comment: Yeah it builds well when it finds new versions in source-control . It just invoke these commands only -:
        [CruiseControl] Invoking Rake task "db:test:load"
        [CruiseControl] Invoking Rake task "db:migrate"
        [CruiseControl] Invoking Rake task "test"
but it didnt deploy my app ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys thanks after looking into code i find out that we can deploy -:

1.Either you can use ccrb_cap_deployer.rb plugin to do so , but it is little bit buggy so i made some changes in the path and pushed the code into git again here

```
https://vparihar01@github.com/webonise/cruisecontrol.git 
# in mean time I add some more plugins and features . Also add the wiki for proper step how to setup cruise control server and how make it customize as per your need
```

Now we had to add these two lines inside the project configuration  file **/.cruise/projects/your_project/cruise_config.rb**

```
project.cap_deployer.emails = ['asda@fsdfsfsdfs.com'] #here add the email to notify given user if deployment is successful or not 
project.cap_deployer.stages = ['staging','production'] #here add the where you want to deploy test , staging or production
```

Also this plugin only let deploy the code into respective servers when the build is successful . Cheers

2.Second way is to create one shell script named it as **build_script.sh** to this path **/.cruise/projects/your_project/work/**

After that add

```
  #!/bin/bash
  # conditionally install project gems from Gemfile
  bundle check || bundle install || exit 1
  cap deploy
```

lines into the build_script.sh and save , Then add **project.build_command = './build_script.sh'** inside the project configuration  file **/.cruise/projects/your_project/cruise_config.rb**
Now everthing done and works fine but in second method the problem is that if the build fails as well then also your code is deployed to server . SO i think that is a bad approach .
Thanks for help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl isn't supposed to deploy your app.

When you want to deploy your app (after many successful cruisecontrol tests against many commits to source control, you'll then:

`cap deploy`